# SFDX:Diff File Against Org command not working only for Apex Classes

Tags: apex, vs-code, diff

In my VS Code, when I right-click on an Apex class I can't see 'SFDX:Diff File Against Org' command. But this is perfectly working for Aura components or Visualforce Pages. The problem only exists with Apex classes.
I have reinstalled VS code two or three times to solve this issue. And also tried 'sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff' command to install the plugin.

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/source-diff/

But nothing worked for me.Can someone hlep me out to solve this issue if you have gone through this before?

[image]

Comment: Did you run "sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff" to install the plug-in?

Comment: @Bahman.A yes Bahaman. But it didn't work